# eRRORServer returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: https://ipv4.google.com/

Tags: java, bufferedreader, urlconnection, stringbuffer

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Rough_Program 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  
  {
    String inputLine = null;
    String contant = null;
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "10.10.10.1");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");
    URL oracle = new URL("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Old%20Trafford");
    StringBuffer str1 = new StringBuffer();
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    yc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            yc.getInputStream()));
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        str1.append(inputLine);
    }
    contant = str1.toString();
    System.out.println(contant);
  }
}
```

Comment: code working on other url's but not hit on www.google.com. i want to fetch the address and phone from google. but it showing error 503. pls help me anyone.

Comment: see [http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html) for a desrciption of 503 and how you can fix it.

Comment: @jane i checked your shared link it is not helpful. google site working fine in browser. but using java it show error.

Answer (score 0):

try to add proxy settings for `https`:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "10.10.10.1");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "3128");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. i have tried according to your way set the property but same error occurred.